# Normalized vector function returns unexpected result

Tags: math, vector, normalization

I am having a problem understanding the vector normalization function.

I have this vector normalization function:

```
function vectorNormalization(vector) {
    var magnitude = Math.sqrt((vector[0] * vector[0]) + (vector[1] * vector[1]) +
                    (vector[2] * vector[2]));

    var x = vector[0] / magnitude;
    var y = vector[1] / magnitude;
    var z = vector[2] / magnitude;

    return [x, y, z];
}
```

These are the result of the reduction between the two vectors (using in a 3D software).

```
[X: -0.004805074799706634, Y: 0.19191680472036263, Z: -0.002017289400100708]
```

The vector normalization function returns this:

```
[-0.025028054575754678,0.99963152765883,-0.010507397138519977]
```

The Y value is too high, it supposed to be normalized and represent a unit but it results in a much higher number. The unit should be less than the value before the normalization.

As you can see, I am dealing with a 3D coordinate system with decimal accuracy. The division is yielding this. I think I need to do something that should take the decimal precision into account, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is correct.  Normalization projects the vector onto the unit sphere.  The original vector has magnitude of 0.191987547 which is less than 1 and so normalization will cause the magnitude to increase.  You can verify this to be the case by computing the magnitude of the resulting normalized vector and see that its magnitude is essentially 1.0.

Further, you can see that the Y component of the original is substantially longer than the X or Z components, so it's not surprising it will be very close to 1 in the normalized vector.

Comment: Is there a way to get a unit that won't be higher. I am trying to animate object in a direction until object 2. using this function, the object will pass the second object on the y-axis in the first iteration of adding these values in the loop, and therefore it doesn't represent a smaller unit within that range, a unit that is a subset of the whole range between the two vectors. Is there a function that can give me a unit that incremental of it will represent a portion of the distance.

Comment: I think you need something other than vector normalization.  In the case above you apply a scaling factor of 1/vec_mag where vec_mag is the magnitude of the vector.  You could impose a lower bound or some other constraint on the scaling factor.  Ultimately what you'll need to do, though, is define the behavior you're looking for and then define an algorithm for computing the scaling factor based upon that desire.